# Ошибка передачи

Tags: java, android, исключения

Пожалуй частая проблема многих, но увы так ответ и не нашёл
А проблема, вернее ошибка заключается в следующем:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=65551, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity {md.site.md/md.site.md.activities.Activity_Md}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 22, size is 4
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)

Ну а также выделяет ошибки в конкретных строках

1. Во фрагменте `service.upload1(file1, str, stringMap, new CancelableCallback(mSelectPath.get(position)) {`
2. `uploadPhoto(mSelectPath, position, controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().size() - 1);`
3. В активити `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Возможно для понимания каких то моментов недостаточно, прошу уточнить в комментариях(всё необходимое добавлю).

Comment: Указано ли в стакТрейсе на какой конкретно строке валится? Покажите как вы и с чем setResult вызываете\

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, именно эти строки я и указал в списках.
Уточните пожалуйста вторую часть вопроса, Вам интересует как реализован метод onActivityResult? Или я как то неверно понял.

Comment: Приведённой вами инфы недостаточно. У вас происходит где-то выход за границы массива. Наверное вы что-то где-то не так делаете. А нужен код где вы, видимо, в Интент кладёте данные

Comment: Вы пытаетесь получить несуществующий элемент с индексом 22  из списка, в котором элементов всего 4 - `mSelectPath.get(position)`, или же тут `controlList.get(position)`